# Show the "input-element" of an ITreeContentProvider in its TreeView

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, contextmenu, eclipse-gef

Hi my goal is to add a new subitem to the "input-object" of a ITreeContentProvider. I am talking about the Object you have to pass to the ITreeContentProviders getElements(Object inputElement)-function.

**Is there a way to make the inputElement show up as the root-element in the TreeView, so i can select it?**

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `TreeViewer.setInput` to change the root element of the tree.

If you want keep changing the root of the tree you could look at using `org.eclipse.ui.part.DrillDownComposite` which adds some controls to move around in the tree:

```
DrillDownComposite drillDown = new DrillDownComposite(this, SWT.BORDER);

// Create tree viewer inside drill down.
treeViewer = new TreeViewer(drillDown, SWT.NONE);

drillDown.setChildTree(treeViewer);
```

which looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the DrillDownComposite-Hint ;) I solved my problem by wrapping my root item into another Class its only purpose is to be the root of the tree. My problem was that my actual root is the item i want to display in the tree but showing it in getElements results in a recursive loop.